# Image Upload Programmatically in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on API that needs to add feature image but cannot use wordpress function to finish my goal. Can anyone tell me where and in which table of wordpress db the image is stored ?

And what i need to do to upload the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow This Step.

> To upload the image without wp function you need to create a field in 
>   wp_postmeta with meta_key = "_wp_attached_file" and 
>   meta_velue="your_file_path".